# i wanna crop image before upload in frontend (react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-hooks

**this is product form component i wanna crop the image and upload it without backend then upload it to firebase storage**

*i wanna crop it automatically or manually in constant aspect ratio to fit card or i want crop it in card itself i tried to use react-image-crop but i didn't success it need alot of setup and i don't know how to do it*

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Input from '../../components/input/input.component'
import Button from '../../components/button/button.component'
import {db} from '../../firebase'
import './addproduct.styles.scss'
import { storage } from 'firebase'
import Spinner from '../../components/spinner/spinner.component'
const AddProduct = ({catigories}) => {
    const [name,setName] = useState('')
    const [price,setPrice] = useState('')
    const [catigory,setCatigory] = useState('')
    const [newCatigoryName,setNewCatigoryName] = useState('')
    const [newCatigoryImg,setNewCatigorImg] = useState(null)
    const [image,setImage] = useState(null)
    const [isSending,setIsSending] = useState(false)
    console.log(image)
    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        if(name && price  && image && catigory){
            setIsSending(true)
            if(catigory === 'addNewCatigory' && newCatigoryImg && newCatigoryName){
                await storage().ref().child(`catigories/${newCatigoryName}.jpg`).put(newCatigoryImg)
                const catigoryImgUrl = await storage().ref().child(`catigories/${newCatigoryName}.jpg`).getDownloadURL()
                await db.collection('catigories').doc(newCatigoryName).set({
                    name:newCatigoryName,
                    imgUrl:catigoryImgUrl
                })
                const storageId = `${name}-${price}-${catigory}`
                await storage().ref().child(`products/${storageId}.jpg`).put(image)
                const productImgUrl = await storage().ref().child(`products/${storageId}.jpg`).getDownloadURL()
                await db.collection('products').add({
                    name:name,
                    price: parseInt(price),
                    imgUrl:productImgUrl,
                    catigory:newCatigoryName
                })
                setIsSending(false)
            }else{
                const storageId = `${name}-${price}-${catigory}`
                await storage().ref().child(`products/${storageId}.jpg`).put(image)
                const productImgUrl = await storage().ref().child(`products/${storageId}.jpg`).getDownloadURL()
                await db.collection('products').add({
                    name:name,
                    price: parseInt(price),
                    imgUrl:productImgUrl,
                    catigory:catigory
                })
                setIsSending(false)
            }
        }
        
    }
    if(isSending){
        return <Spinner />
    }
    return (
        <div className='product'>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="product__form">
                <Input placeholder='Enter Product Name' value={name} setValue={setName} width='100%' fontSize='20px' height='40px' borderRadius='20px'type='text' margin />            
                <Input placeholder='Product Price' value={price} setValue={setPrice} width='100%' fontSize='20px' height='40px' borderRadius='20px'type='number' margin />            
                <input type="file" onChange={(event) => event.target.files[0] ? setImage(event.target.files[0]) :null}/> 
                <select className='product__form__select' onChange={(event) => setCatigory(event.target.value)}>
                    <option value=''>Catigories</option>
                    {catigories.map(item => <option key={item.name} value={item.name}>{item.name}</option>)}
                    <option value='addNewCatigory'>other</option>
                </select>
                {catigory === 'addNewCatigory' ? 
                    <div className='product__form__addcatigory'>
                        <Input placeholder='Catigory Name' value={newCatigoryName} setValue={setNewCatigoryName} width='100%' fontSize='20px' height='40px' borderRadius='20px'type='text' margin />
                        <input type="file" onChange={(event) => event.target.files[0] ? setNewCatigorImg(event.target.files[0]) :null}/> 
                    </div>
                    : null
                }
                <Button title='add Item' width='100px' height='40px' style={{borderRadius:'20px'}}/>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default AddProduct
```

Answer (score 7):

You can crop the image just after selecting the image in front end. For cropping the image these 2 module are best.

1. [React-easy-crop](https://github.com/ricardo-ch/react-easy-crop)
2. [React-image-crop](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image-crop).

Integration of these module is also simple.

Answer (score 3):

I've recently [blogged](https://medium.com/swlh/adding-crop-before-upload-in-react-22dfcf3a95b7) about how to do this using [react-uploady](https://github.com/rpldy/react-uploady).

Check out this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/crop-and-upload-react-uploady-fixed-aspect-ok9gn?file=/src/App.js) for the full example.

The code uses react-image-crop but its not tied to it in any way, so you can replace it with any other crop solution you desire.

It boils down to:

```js
import React, { useState, useCallback, useRef } from "react";
import ReactCrop from "react-image-crop";
import "react-image-crop/dist/ReactCrop.css";
import Uploady, { withRequestPreSendUpdate } from "@rpldy/uploady";
import UploadButton from "@rpldy/upload-button";
import UploadPreview from "@rpldy/upload-preview";
import cropImage from "./cropImage";

const ItemPreviewWithCrop = withRequestPreSendUpdate((props) => {
  const { url, updateRequest, requestData } = props;
  const [crop, setCrop] = useState({ aspect: 4 / 3 });

  const onUploadCrop = useCallback(async () => {
    if (updateRequest && (crop?.height || crop?.width)) {
      requestData.items[0].file = await cropImage(url, requestData.items[0].file, crop);
      updateRequest({ items: requestData.items });
    }
  }, [url, requestData, updateRequest, crop]);

  return (
    <>
      <ReactCrop
        src={url}
        crop={crop}
        onChange={setCrop}
        onComplete={setCrop}
      />
      <br/>
      <button onClick={onUploadCrop}>Upload Cropped</button>
    </>
  );
});

export default function App() {
  const previewMethodsRef = useRef();

  return (
    <Uploady destination={{ url: "[upload-url]" }} multiple={false}>
      <br />
      <UploadButton>Select File</UploadButton>
      <br />
      <UploadPreview
        PreviewComponent={ItemPreviewWithCrop}
        previewComponentProps={{ previewMethods: previewMethodsRef }}
        previewMethodsRef={previewMethodsRef}       
      />
    </Uploady>
  );
}
```

It will show the selected file in the crop area with fixed 4/3 aspect ratio (just an example).